# How to prepare query to check from another table and then fetch from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table one is random_questions and another is personal_questions,Ii want to check copy_id column in personal_questions where `personal_questions.question_to = current_session_user` and `personal_question.copy_id = random_question.id`....

Here is my code :

```
$session_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT random_questions.id AS id, random_questions.question_by_id AS question_by_id, random_questions.question AS question, random_questions.total_answers AS answers FROM random_questions INNER JOIN personal_questions WHERE (random_questions.total_answers != '8') OR (personal_questions.question_to != '$session_user' AND personal_questions.copy_id != random_questions.id)");
```

I am not getting the results properly, if personal_questions's copy_id is equals to any of random_questions's id then results repeats automatically. I hope you  understand. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from   random_questions   p,
       personal_questions a
where  a.question_to = current_session_user
and    a.copy_id     = p.id;
```